# How to modify unix zip archive file structure on creation?

Tags: unix, zip

I'm currently using the following command to create a zip archive of a directory and all directories / files inside of that.

```
zip /home/ubuntu/output.zip -r /home/ubuntu/dir_to_zip
```

I am forced to use the absolute path for both paths because the command is to be run via a shell script in a different location.

The problem I'm running into is that inside the zip archive that is created, a `home` directory exists, and inside that an `ubuntu` directory, then `dir_to_zip`, and then everything as it should be inside that.

How can I get the archive to only contain what is inside of `dir_to_zip` without passing a relative path to the zip command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change to the directory before running zip. You can do it like this:

```
( cd /home/ubuntu/dir_to_zip && zip /home/ubuntu/output.zip -r . )
```

Since the command is within parentheses, it will be executed in a subshell environment, so the `cd` will not change the current directory of the base shell.